# civicrm how to identify the php page

Tags: php, drupal, crm

I want to edit civicrm custom form section.

I can not find the PHP page.

Comment: What exactly do you want to edit? Change the custom fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the CiviCRM Floss Book:

http://en.flossmanuals.net/civicrm/ch062_introduction

Also check:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC33/Customizing+CiviCRM+Screens

Finally might be better off posting this on the civicrm forums :)

lobo